# How can I find decryption of the message modulo p and q for RSA-CRT?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

If I have only n and m(message), how can I find decryption of the message modulo p and q (to be merged by CRT)?

Comment: I can guess that p and q are the RSA primes and n=p*q, but what is m? Please use standard notation or, even better, actual words.

Comment: Sorry, m is the message.

Comment: If m is message then you have the message so you're done. Assuming m is the ciphertext then there is no easy solution. You must factor n.